# Recursive object access to private methods

Tags: java

Why does the following code print "YO"?  Whose `printYo()` is being called?  I would think that this code would not compile because `printYo()` is private to `t`.

```
public class Test {
    private void printYo() {
        System.out.println("YO");
    }

    public void doubleTrouble(Test t) {
        t.printYo();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.doubleTrouble(new Test());
    }
}
```

What can I do to make sure the outer object doesn't mutate the argument class?

Comment: The method is private to the source file/class, not to an instance.

Comment: because private members can be accessed by other methods in same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> printYo() is private to t

No. That method is `private` in regards to the class `Test`. Any piece of code within `Test` can use it.

> What can I do to make sure the outer object doesn't mutate the argument class?

Java does not have any built in mechanism to refuse access to members on a per instance basis. (If that is what you meant.)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method with in the class , which sound correct for the output . Even if you call the main method from different class it gives the same output.